# Why does the confidence boundary contain fewer points than expected in R (`ggplot`)?

Tags: r, confidence-interval, ggplot2

I use a LOESS regression and draw a confidence boundary with a 99% level.

```r
# R code
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mtcars) + 
  aes(x = mpg, y = disp) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(level = 0.99, method = "loess")
```

[image]

Why are there way fewer than 99% points in the confidence boundary? (7 points out of 32 are outside the confidence boundary).

Is it because it's only an estimate of the confidence boundary, and not the "real" one?

Comment: You'd probably want a tolerance interval.

Answer (score 6):

The reason this happens is because a confidence interval quantifies the uncertainty about a fixed parameter (here: the mean at a given point) rather than the sample. This means that as the number of observations grows bigger, the width of the confidence interval actually goes to $0$. In the limit, the proportion of data point inside the confidence interval goes to $0$ (see comments)!

A different way to quantify uncertainty of your data is by a [prediction interval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prediction_interval) that additionally quantifies the uncertainty stemming from sampling variability.

Comment: Is it true to state that if I fit 100 loess regression lines with 100 samples, 99 lines will fall in the confidence interval at a given point (in grey on the chart)?

Comment: Asymptotically, the number of points inside the confidence interval is $O(\sqrt n).$  That's a *lot* more than "no data points"!

Comment: @whuber I did not think too closely about this when typing - thanks for pointing it out! So the _proportion_ of points in the CI is $\mathcal O(\frac {1} {\sqrt{n}})$, so as $n \to \infty$ the _proportion_ of points inside the CI goes to $0$. However, I am wondering under which assumptions your $\mathcal O(\sqrt n)$ holds (e.g. normality)?  You could also have a symmetric distribution with no mass around $0$; then the amount of points inside the CI would also go to $0$; right?

Comment: I have adopted assumptions similar to those implicit in your analysis, including that the CI is for a mean, conditional mean, conditional quantile, or some such property we can compare data values to.  We don't need normality: we only need a distribution continuous in a neighborhood of the parameter and a CI procedure whose expected width is $O(1/\sqrt n).$  Symmetry is unnecessary.  Stated so broadly I'm sure there are counterexamples, but your point (I think) is to explain the behavior of commonly used CI procedures, not every procedure.

Comment: Thanks! I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: @Stefan What about my statement in the comment?

Comment: No, Julien, because that mischaracterizes confidence intervals.  It might just so happen that *this* interval based on *these* data is far from realistic, so that in the next 1000 cases most results will not lie within it.

Comment: I don't understand your answer